# filter multi-indexed grouped pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, multi-index

**The data** looks like the following:

```
id  timestamp   date        value
1   2001-01-01  2001-05-01  0
1   2001-10-01  2001-05-01  1
2   2001-01-01  2001-05-01  0
2   2001-10-01  2001-05-01  0
```

as you see the table contains the columns `id`, `timestamp`, `date` and `value`.
Every row with the same `id` also has the same `date`.
Furthermore `date` is timewise always somewhere in between the first and the last `timestamp` of each `id`.

**The task** is to filter the table in the way to remove every `id` which does not contain at least one entry with `value > 0` at a timestamp after their individual `date`.

I implemented it in the way that I multi-index the table with `level 0 = id` and `level 1 = date` and sort it. Then I group it by `level 0`. Next I loop through every group (`id`) and assign a new value telling me if the `id` is "good" (boolean). Finally I filter the table where good is `True`.

Unfortunately this implementation is slow like hell for a big (>10M rows) dataset.
I am looking for a way to speed this up. My idea was using `groupby.apply(lambda g: something)`  but I did not get it to work and I do not know if this is the fastest option possible.

Working Code Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                   'timestamp': ['01-01-2001', '01-10-2001', '01-01-2001', '01-10-2001'], 
                   'date': ['01-05-2001', '01-05-2001', '01-05-2001', '01-05-2001'],
                   'value': [0, 1, 0, 0]})                               

df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index(['id','timestamp']).sort_index()
grouped = df.groupby(level=0)
df['good'] = False
for i,(id,df_id) in enumerate(grouped):
    index = df_id.index
    df_id = df_id.droplevel(0)
    df.good.loc[index] = any(df_id.value.loc[df_id.date[0]:] > 0)
df = df[df.good == True]
```

Comment: I think you create new question ;)

Comment: Because here are 3 question hidden ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For get all `id`s by `1` in `value` column and also `timestamp` are higher like `date` create 2 masks by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html), chain by `&` for bitwise `AND` and then test if at least one `True` per group by [`GroupBy.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.any.html) and [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','timestamp'])

m = df['value'].gt(0) & df['timestamp'].gt(df['date'])
df = df[m.groupby(df['id']).transform('any')]
print (df)
   id  timestamp       date  value
0   1 2001-01-01 2001-01-05      0
1   1 2001-01-10 2001-01-05      1
```

Comment: wow thanks! How would I solve it if I want to add some days as "buffer" to the date, like `import datetime
any(df_id.value.loc[df_id.date[0]+ datetime.timedelta(days=1):] > 0`

Comment: @gustavz - Do you think like `m = df['value'].gt(0) & df['timestamp'].gt(df['date'] + pd.Timedelta(days=1))` ?

Comment: How would i change your code if i want to know: Give me all data time-wise after `date` from the first value greater `0`  for each individual `id`?  So not just all the data greater zero after a certain date, but just the data after the date starting from the time-wise first value greater zero.

Comment: @gustavz - Not sure if understand, can you add some sample data with expected output, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: I edited the input data. Only data after `date` should be taken

Comment: @gustavz - Can you check now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212784/discussion-between-gustavz-and-jezrael).