# filter and extend time-series pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, filtering

This question is an addon to this question: [filter multi-indexed grouped pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074421/filter-multi-indexed-grouped-pandas-dataframe)

I would like to get the `timestamp` where `value` starts to be greater zero after `date` as new column `new_date` for each individual `id`

Example Input data:

```
id timestamp  date       value
1  2001-01-01 2001-05-01 1
1  2001-10-01 2001-05-01 0
1  2001-10-02 2001-05-01 1
1  2001-10-03 2001-05-01 0
1  2001-10-04 2001-05-01 1
2  2001-01-01 2001-05-01 1
2  2001-10-01 2001-05-01 0
2  2001-10-02 2001-05-01 0
2  2001-10-03 2001-05-01 0
2  2001-10-04 2001-05-01 1
```

Wanted Output data example:

```
id timestamp  date       value new_date
1  2001-01-01 2001-05-01 1     2001-10-02
1  2001-10-01 2001-05-01 0     2001-10-02
1  2001-10-02 2001-05-01 1     2001-10-02
1  2001-10-03 2001-05-01 0     2001-10-02
1  2001-10-04 2001-05-01 1     2001-10-02
2  2001-01-01 2001-05-01 1     2001-10-04
2  2001-10-01 2001-05-01 0     2001-10-04
2  2001-10-02 2001-05-01 0     2001-10-04
2  2001-10-03 2001-05-01 0     2001-10-04
2  2001-10-04 2001-05-01 1     2001-10-04
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplier solution working also if some group has no match  is first filter `DataFrame` chained mask for greater like `date` by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) with bitwise `AND` same for `0`, then remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), create `Series` and last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','timestamp'])

m = df['timestamp'].gt(df['date']) & df['value'].gt(0)

s = df[m].drop_duplicates('id').set_index('id')['timestamp']

df['new_date'] = df['id'].map(s)
print (df)
   id  timestamp       date  value   new_date
0   1 2001-01-01 2001-05-01      1 2001-10-02
1   1 2001-10-01 2001-05-01      0 2001-10-02
2   1 2001-10-02 2001-05-01      1 2001-10-02
3   1 2001-10-03 2001-05-01      0 2001-10-02
4   1 2001-10-04 2001-05-01      1 2001-10-02
5   2 2001-01-01 2001-05-01      1 2001-10-04
6   2 2001-10-01 2001-05-01      0 2001-10-04
7   2 2001-10-02 2001-05-01      0 2001-10-04
8   2 2001-10-03 2001-05-01      0 2001-10-04
9   2 2001-10-04 2001-05-01      1 2001-10-04
```