# filter time-series pandas dataframe by column value

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, filtering

This question is an addon to this question: [filter multi-indexed grouped pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61074421/filter-multi-indexed-grouped-pandas-dataframe)

I want all data (time-wise) after `date` starting from the first `value` greater zero. (applied for every `id`)

Example Input data:

```
id  timestamp   date        value
1   2001-01-01  2001-05-01  1
1   2001-10-01  2001-05-01  0
1   2001-10-02  2001-05-01  1
1   2001-10-03  2001-05-01  0
1   2001-10-04  2001-05-01  1
```

Wanted Output data example:

```
id  timestamp   date        value
1   2001-10-02  2001-05-01  1
1   2001-10-03  2001-05-01  0
1   2001-10-04  2001-05-01  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) by another column, then create [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html), filter for greater like `0` and last add removed values by [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','timestamp'])

m = df['timestamp'].gt(df['date'])
m1 = df[m].groupby('id')['value'].cumsum().gt(0).reindex(df.index, fill_value=False)
df = df[m1]
print (df)
   id  timestamp       date  value
2   1 2001-10-02 2001-05-01      1
3   1 2001-10-03 2001-05-01      0
4   1 2001-10-04 2001-05-01      1
```

Another idea with replace column by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.sort_values(['id','timestamp'])

m = df['timestamp'].gt(df['date'])
m1 = df.assign(value = df['value'].where(m, 0)).groupby('id')['value'].cumsum().gt(0)
df = df[m1]
print (df)
   id  timestamp       date  value
2   1 2001-10-02 2001-05-01      1
3   1 2001-10-03 2001-05-01      0
4   1 2001-10-04 2001-05-01      1
```